# Inconsistency between pandas.DataFrame.plot(kind='box') and pandas.DataFrame.boxplot()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, boxplot

I have encountered the following problem when trying to make a boxplot of one column in a pandas.DataFrame vs another one. Here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(60))
df.columns = ['Values']
names = ('one','two','three')*int(df.shape[0]/3)
df['Names'] = names

df.plot(x='Names', y='Values', kind='box')
df.boxplot(column='Values', by='Names')
```

I expect two plot to be the same, but I get:

[image: plots]

**Is it an expected behavior and if so, how the expression for the first plot should be changed to match the second one?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.boxplot()` and `.plot(kind='box')`/`.plot.box()` are separate implementations. Problem with `.plot(kind='box')`/`.plot.box()` is that although the argument `by` exists, it is not implemented and therefore ignored (see [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15079) for example, and they [never managed to document it properly](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/20373)), meaning that you won't be able to reproduce the result you get with `.boxplot()`.

Tl;dr `.plot(kind='box')`/`.plot.box()` implemented poorly, use `.boxplot()` instead.